# What are packages and repositories?

Tags: package-management

What is meant by packages and repository in Ubuntu?

I see a new thing in Ubuntu that it is required to update packages for installing any software.

So question is that what are these two terms?

Answer (score 1):

## Repository

A software repository contains software packages. When you search via the Software Centre or use a tool like `apt` or `apt-get` you are shown a list of all the packages within the repositories available to your system.

A software repository can store its files on one server or across many different servers known as mirrors.

## Package

A package refers to a compressed file archive containing all of the files that come with a particular application.

The files are usually stored in the package according to their relative installation paths on your system. Most packages also contain installation instructions for the OS, as well as a list of any other packages that are dependencies (prerequisites required for installation.